# A solution for end user to design business process using Windows Workflow Foundation

Tags: workflow-foundation

I want to design a solution using WF, where an end user can design workflows based on their business needs. I want to make the solution as much as flexible where the user does not need to do any code.

here are some thoughts -

1. I need to create Custom Activities based on business process.
2. The end user will use a designer(VS 2008) to drag and drop activities to design a workflow.
3. If the end user wants to use EventDrivenActivity to call external methods, then there is a need of an interface which derives from ExternalDataExchange. and events which will be invoked..How this is possible using custom activities.
4. A workflow needs a host to drive the instance of workflow. In my case its a web service.
   Everytime a new workflow is added, the webservice, which starts the worklfow runtime needs to know the "type" and "parameters" to create and start the workflow instance.

This , I think will be the job of a developer to attach it in program. Or is there a way to achieve this declaratively, Say Web service is up on IIS, and a new workflow type is added in the config (I am not sure, just guess..)

I want to know, if i am on right track to achieve this solution or missed some .

Experts please guide. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you'd like to re-host the workflow designer so the end-user can edit the workflow.

There is a good article on [Hosting the WF Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480213.aspx) that you may find a decent starting point.